# Hiding class from the test name in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have a testclass inside a module. Both testclass and module have more or less the same name and I don't expect to have the second class in this module.

My pytest output looks like this:

```
test_vlans.py::TestVlan::test_normal[delete_vlans] PASSED                              [  4%]
test_vlans.py::TestVlan::test_normal[alter_vlans] PASSED                               [  8%]
test_vlans.py::TestVlan::test_normal[add_vlans] PASSED                                 [ 13%]
test_vlans.py::TestVlan::test_idempotence[delete_vlans] PASSED                         [ 17%]
...
```

Testclass:

```py
class TestVlan(BasicTestScenario):
    target = "vlans"
```

I feel like `TestVlan` is redundant here. How to exclude class name from the test name?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "exclude" - do you want to customize the pytest output?

Answer (score 0):

From the [naming conventions](https://docs.pytest.org/en/reorganize-docs/new-docs/user/naming_conventions.html):

> If tests are defined as methods on a class, the class name should start with “Test”, as in TestExample.

From that, I would assume (a) you don't *have* to call your class `TestVlan` but (b) you *should* start with `Test`, even though you don't *have* to.